# Search for a substring in an another string using hashing

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash

I wrote code to find a substring in another string using hashing, but it's giving me a wrong result.

A description of how the code works:

1. Store the first `n` powers of `p=31` in array `pows`.
2. Store hashes for each substring `s[0..i]` in the array `h`.
3. Calculate the hash for each substring of length 9 using the `h` array and store it in a set.
4. Hash the string `t` and store its hash.
5. Compare the hash of `t` and hashes in the set.

The hash `h[n2-1]` should exist in the set but it does not. Could you help me find the bug in the code?

Note: When I use the modular inverse instead of multiplying by `pows[i-8]` the code runs well.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define m 1000000007
#define N (int)2e6 + 3

using namespace std;

long long pows[N], h[N], h2[N];

set<int> ss;

int main() {

    string s = "www.cplusplus.com/forum";

    // powers array
    pows[0] = 1;
    int n = s.length(), p = 31;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        pows[i] = pows[i - 1] * p;
        pows[i] %= m;
    }

    // hash from 0 to i array
    h[0] = s[0] - 'a' + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        h[i] = h[i - 1] + (s[i] - 'a' + 1) * pows[i];
        h[i] %= m;
    }

    // storing each hash with 9 characters in a set
    ss.insert(h[8]);
    for (int i = 9; i < n; i++) {
        int tp = h[i] - h[i - 9] * pows[i - 8];
        tp %= m;
        tp += m;
        tp %= m;
        ss.insert(tp);
    }

    // print hashes with 9 characters
    set<int>::iterator itr = ss.begin();
    while (itr != ss.end()) {
        cout << *(itr++) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // t is the string that i want to check if it is exist in s
    string t = "cplusplus";
    int n2 = t.length();
    h2[0] = t[0] - 'a' + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n2; i++) {
        h2[i] = h2[i - 1] + (t[i] - 'a' + 1) * pows[i];
        h2[i] %= m;
    }
    // print t hash
    cout << h2[n2 - 1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems with your code:

1. When you're computing hashes for substrings of length 9, you're storing the intermediate result (of type `long long`) in an `int` variable. This could cause integer overflow and the hash you computed would probably be incorrect.
2. Given a string `s = {s[0], s[1], ..., s[n-1]}`, the way you're computing the hash is: `h = ∑ s[i] * p^i`. In this case, given the prefix hash stored in `h`, the hash for a substring `s[l..r]` (inclusive) should be `(h[r] - h[l - 1]) / p^(r-l+1)`, instead of what you wrote. This is also why using modular inverse (which is required to perform division under modulo) is correct.

I think a more common way to compute hashes is the other way around, i.e. `h = ∑ s[i] * p^(n-i-1)`. This allows you to compute the substring hash as `h[r] - h[l - 1] * p^(r-l+1)`, which does not require computing modular inverses.